# Why can I see the camera gizmo in the 3D View but not the actual camera itself?

Tags: interface, camera

[image]

I am new to Blender. The camera widget in my viewport only displays as a dot and yellow rectangle, while in the tutorials it has a pyramid shaped bounding box and arrow indicating which way is up. How do I correct this?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the tutorial camera and your camera. I don't think there is a way to change the appearance of the camera, perhaps you are mistaking somethin else for it?

Comment: Thanks Leander - see above

Comment: What version of Blender is this?  Were you using Beta/Experimental versions of 2.80 prior to this?  You may have to reset your user settings to factory default.

Comment: 2.80 - downloaded yesterday from Blender.org. Did File/Defaults/Load Factory Settings, but camera still looks the same.

Comment: Was it like this right from the start?

Comment: Yes, from the start.

Comment: That is weird, maybe it is a persistent settings across multiple 2.8 versions.

Answer (score 4):

What you are seeing is the camera's gizmo, which only shows up when selecting the camera object.

To see the camera wire shape, enable **Extras** under *Objects* in the 3D Views *Overlay* options.

[image: overlay settings]

Make sure, camera visibility is on.

[image: visibility]

Comment: Thanks Leander. Have tried that, but camera gizmo unchanged.

Comment: Can you see other shapes like the lamp?

Comment: Yes, and if I change the light from Point to Sun to Spot, the light gizmo changes to a different shape...

Comment: Camera visibility on...

Comment: UI settings are usually saved in the blend file. Can you upload your file to blend-exchange.giantcowfils.com and include it in your post?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6470" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6470/)

Comment: I previously had 2.7, which I uninstalled completely, then installed 2.80

Comment: I can see the camera shape in your example file. Have you tried to reset to factory settings? *File > Load Factory Settings*

Comment: Just did File>Defaults>Load Factory Settings... but no change to camera gizmo

Comment: I am sorry, then I am all out of ideas. If it worked in 2.79 it could be a graphics card/driver problem (but I don't think so). If you haven't done anything weird to your system before installing blender 2.8, it might be good to make a bug report (https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/). You should add the things you tried to the question, so that it gets bumped. I'll leave my answer for others to find. If it doesn't get upvoted this thread will automatically get bumped.

Comment: Thanks for trying, Leander

Comment: Hi Leander, Hi Abid,

My IT guy just updated the video card drivers - I can now see the camera gizmo.

There were a few other wierd things happening before the driver update. Shadows were not showing (in Eevee mode with Viewport Shading in Rendered mode). Also If I selected the Material option in the properties panel on the right hand side, Blender would just close down. With the driver update, this is now fixed.

Thanks for your help.